# Problemas com Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-security

Olá, pessoal. Estou criando um projeto utilizando Java EE e como IDE estou usando o Eclipse.

Neste projeto, estou usando o Spring Security para autenticar o procedimento do login. 
Só que acontece o seguinte: eu criei uma página xhtml para cadastrar novos usuários.
Obviamente, quem acessa esta página não possui cadastro, pois ela está entrando nesta página
exatamente para criar um novo cadastro.

Nesta parte, o Spring Security serve para que os usuários não acessem as páginas internas do sistema
diretamente. Quando alguém tenta acessar alguma página interna sem passar pela tela de login, o Spring automaticamente redireciona o usuário para a página default. Mas eu quero retirar esta restrição SOMENTE PARA A PÁGINA DE CADASTRO DE USUÁRIOS para que qualquer usuário consiga acessar a página de cadastro mesmo sem realizar o login.

Alguém conheceria algum método para realizar este procedimento?

Estou postando o conteúdo do arquivo **applicationcontext.xml** do meu projeto. Acredito que é neste arquivo que é necessário realizar alguma alteração.

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <beans:bean id="appUserDetailsService"
        class="com.sisRastrbov.security.AppUserDetailsService" />

    <http pattern="/Login.xhtml" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/Erro.xhtml" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/Main.xhtml" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" security="none" />

    <http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/gado/**" access="hasAnyRole('ADMINISTRADORES')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/usuario/**" access="hasAnyRole('ADMINISTRADORES','FUNCIONARIOS')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/tag/**" access="hasAnyRole('ADMINISTRADORES','FUNCIONARIOS')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/propriedade/**" access="hasAnyRole('ADMINISTRADORES','FUNCIONARIOS')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/MinhasProp.xhtml" access="hasAnyRole('ADMINISTRADORES','FUNCIONARIOS')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/area/**" access="hasAnyRole('ADMINISTRADORES','FUNCIONARIOS')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/Home.xhtml" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/Main.xhtml" access="isAuthenticated()" />

        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />

        <form-login login-page="/Main.xhtml" default-target-url="/Home.xhtml" always-use-default-target="true" authentication-failure-url="/Main.xhtml?invalid=true"/>
        <logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" invalidate-session="true"/>
    </http>


    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="appUserDetailsService">
            <!-- <password-encoder hash=""/> -->
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Agradeço a todos que postarem qualquer resposta ou sugestão.

Answer (score 0):

Para permitir que qualquer usuário acesse uma página específica você deve adicionar a seguinte linha:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/cadastro" access="permitAll"/>
```

Mas tem que adicionar depois de:

`<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />`